# vodafone smart first 6 usb debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, usb-debugging

I have a Vodafone smart first 6 phone, that I want to debug over bluetooth. I have turned on usb debugging at developer options and also allowed mock locations. I downloaded the usb driver for it from http://androidxda.com/download-vodafone-usb-drivers . I have windows 8.1 and android studio 1.2.2

When I connect my phone to my computer the phone sais "USB debugging connected" but my android studio doesn't see it, altough my computer recognize it as a media device. The adb devices command isn't see it either.

All this steps worked for me for previous devices, I have debuged a lot of android devices before but I cannot find a solution for this vodafone phone. Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted the two 'vf695' entries in device manager, disconnected the phone, installed PDANet (http://pdanet.co/), selected the 'unknown device' option, followed the instructions, seemed to do the job.

Comment: Thank you, I installed pdanet both my computer and the vodafone device and it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution after 1 week searching go to this blog and you will download all the zip file http://www.mediafire.com/download/5ff6s5bk1couva9/Compelte_USB_Drivers+PDanet+Adb_Installer.rar install first C++ then find Universal ADB DRiver it will get your ABD with ! mark restart you will find you are so so so so happy as I am now don't forget to configure your mobile with this configuration:

1. Setting - Storage - click in to three dots USB computer connection - then choose (MTP) Media Device\
2. We change your mobile device to developer mode click on USB debugging connected and choose USB debugging

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have the phone any more, so I won't be able to try out your solution. (And I also found the solution back then)